# Grep and Split based on the Pattern - shell script

Tags: shell, grep

I have a large text file with a pattern as below:

```
CAT:D1_XCAT_TE_ID=SE0101900     
CAT:D2_XCAT_TE_ID=SF0101900
CAT:D3_XCAT_TE_ID=SG0101900
.
.
.
.
.
.
DLR:1|1|1|606|P|1|1|
DLR:1|2|1|606|P|1|1|
DLR:1|3|1|606|F|1|1|
.
.
.
CAT:D1_XCAT_TE_ID=D0101901
CAT:D2_XCAT_TE_ID=D0101902
CAT:D3_XCAT_TE_ID=D0101903
.
.
.
DLR:1|1|1|607|P|1|1|
DLR:1|2|1|607|P|1|1|
DLR:1|3|1|607|P|1|1|
```

what I need to do is I need to get the keyword "XCAT_TE_ID". Example:

```
Each of CAT:D1xxx will have one DLR:1|1|xxx
CAT:D2xxx will have one DLR:1|2|xxx
CAT:D3xxx will have one DLR:1|3|xxx

Original :
CAT:D1_XCAT_TE_ID=SE0101900

After split:
D1_XCAT_TE_ID - store in one array
SE0101900 - store in another array
```

However, the condition to store in array if only the value at 5th field is "P" from DLR(split by |).

in order to get the DLR for CAT:

```
CAT:D1_XCAT_TE_ID=SE0101900
D1 - this field, number 1 indicates the DLR
To refer to the value of DLR, split the DLR with "|" and get the 2nd field.
2nd field= 1
 then, the value of DLR will be:

DLR:1|1|1|607|P|1|1|

each of CAT record has one DLR record. This is a pair.
```

However, I need to store the value if only the value at 5th field is "P" from DLR(split by |).
I'm not sure how to this. please help.

Comment: What is the 5th field? You really need to provide more details on the file format. My first guess is you might want to use awk

Comment: sorry, it 5th filed at DLR. let me edit the question

Comment: You have not clearly stated what parts of the input go where, or how the CAT and DLR rows are connected.

Comment: Something like "The DLR belonging to the line `Dxxx_XCAT_TE_ID` is the first DLR record with xxx in the second field, `DLR:1|xxx|1|607|P|1`. After each `CAT:` line there willl always be exactly one matching DLR before another  `CAT` line occurs."

Comment: yes, each CAT record will have one DLR.

Comment: This is getting complicated. Please post example output you want to have and most importantly, what have you tried. You can use `grep` to filter the lines, `sed` to extract parts of the line, but you are actually asking about how to marge almost-nonrelated parts or file based on a common key. Also you tagged `shell` and posix shell doesn't has arrays, bash has them. This is way more complicated than simple "grep XCAT_TE_ID" - you have to explain it better and limit it to one problem. For your problem a complicated  `awk` script looks like a solution.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you can read the inputfile once, and will work a lot faster than these repeated commands.  I don't know your experience with `awk`, so I give this slow alternative.
First look for the different `DLR` values with

```
sed -rn 's/^CAT:D([^_]*).*/\1/p' inputfile| sort -u
```

The combination of `-r` and `/p` makes sure only matches are printed.
This command will be the input of the next loop (after `done`):

```
while IFS= read -r dlr; do
   grep -E "^CAT:D${dlr}_|^DLR:[^|]*\|${dlr}\|" inputfile |
      paste -d"=" - - |
      sed -rn 's/[^=]*=([^=]*)=DLR:([^|]*\|){4}P.*/\1/p'
done < <(sed -rn 's/^CAT:D([^_]*).*/\1/p' inputfile | sort -u)
```

This solution supposes that the DLR record only has one `=` (and I can use it in the paste command), and after each CAT record there is exactly one matching DLR record.

First only the lines are selected that are relevant:

```
# results without paste processing
CAT:D1_XCAT_TE_ID=SE0101900
DLR:1|1|1|606|P|1|1|
CAT:D1_XCAT_TE_ID=D0101901
DLR:1|1|1|607|P|1|1|
CAT:D2_XCAT_TE_ID=SF0101900
DLR:1|2|1|606|P|1|1|
CAT:D2_XCAT_TE_ID=D0101902
DLR:1|2|1|607|P|1|1|
CAT:D3_XCAT_TE_ID=SG0101900
DLR:1|3|1|606|F|1|1|
CAT:D3_XCAT_TE_ID=D0101903
DLR:1|3|1|607|P|1|1|
```

Next the `paste` command joins each pair of lines

```
# result without `sed` command (spaces of first record are in the example input)
CAT:D1_XCAT_TE_ID=SE0101900     =DLR:1|1|1|606|P|1|1|
CAT:D1_XCAT_TE_ID=D0101901=DLR:1|1|1|607|P|1|1|
CAT:D2_XCAT_TE_ID=SF0101900=DLR:1|2|1|606|P|1|1|
CAT:D2_XCAT_TE_ID=D0101902=DLR:1|2|1|607|P|1|1|
CAT:D3_XCAT_TE_ID=SG0101900=DLR:1|3|1|606|F|1|1|
CAT:D3_XCAT_TE_ID=D0101903=DLR:1|3|1|607|P|1|1|
```

Now `sed` is used for selecting the lines with `|P` and showing the substring.